# Casting DATETIME on concatenated date and time

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to concatenate a column's date to a fixed time of the day and then `CAST` the whole thing as `DATETIME`.

The fixed time is 5:30am.

The date column I'm using needs to be adjusted as it shows the **end** date/time of when something ran; I want to use the **start** date/time.

The start date/time time is not available as its own column, but I have another column that has the duration the process took in seconds, so I can use `DATEADD` to roll the end date/time back to the start date/time.

Here's the full statement:

`CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(ss,-ConfTask.[LastExecutedDuration], ConfTask.[LastExecutedDate]), 103) + ' ' + '05:30' as DATETIME)`

Here's the error message I'm receiving:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.

I've tried testing these statements to investigate the issue, but they all run OK on their own:

`CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) + ' ' + '05:30' as DATETIME)`

`CAST('2017-03-02' + ' ' + '05:30' as DATETIME)`

`DATEADD(ss,-ConfTask.[LastExecutedDuration], ConfTask.[LastExecutedDate])`

I'm a bit stuck on how to get round this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `ConfTask.[LastExecutedDuration]` stored as a `TIME`, an `INT`, a `NUMERIC()` value...?

Comment: It's stored as `Decimal(18, 0)`

Comment: This can't possibly be connected to the fact that you're converting to a specific format `(103)`, right? Because in your examples you converted `GETDATE()` to `(103)`, but not `ConfTask.[LastExecutedDate])`.  Have you tried running it with a different date format, like `(101)`, or without providing a specific format at all? (Hopefully not a stupid question...)

Comment: I think you're probably on the right track as I tried formatting both the date and the time parts separately and that seems to have worked (see my answer below). Not 100% sure why it works this way, but there you go! Thanks for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

`CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(ss,-ConfTask.[LastExecutedDuration], ConfTask.[LastExecutedDate]), 112)) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), '05:30:00', 108)`

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, you must have some unexpected values in the column.

I would suggest finding them using a query such as this:

```
SELECT LastExecutedDuration, LastExecutedDate
FROM ConfTask
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime,
                  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
                          DATEADD(second,
                                  -ConfTask.[LastExecutedDuration],
                                   ConfTask.[LastExecutedDate]
                                  )
                          103
                         ) + ' ' + '05:30')
                 )
```

You can also simplify the logic, by just using date functions:

```
select dateadd(minute,
               5 * 60 + 30,
               convert(datetime,
                       convert(date,
                               dateadd(second,
                                       - ConfTask.LastExecutedDuration
                                       ConfTask.LastExecutedDate
                                      )
                              )
                      )
              )
```

Comment: Ahh, there were some nulls in the columns I was using. Thanks, this helped me track down the problem.

Comment: I was a bit hasty there... handling the nulls removed the error, but did not return the correct date/time format.